# Issue with mustache template variables

Tags: mustache, swagger-codegen

I have the following bit of json that is generated by the swagger codegen tool, this is the vendor extensions for a API operation:

```
  "vendorExtensions" : {
    "x-rate-limit" : [ {
      "name" : "max",
      "value" : 20,
      "description" : "The max amount of requests allowed within the period"
    }, {
      "name" : "period",
      "value" : 60,
      "description" : "The amount of seconds that we track the amount of requests made"
    } ]
  },
```

When trying to access these variables `name` and `value` in my mustache template is coming up blank:

```
    {{#vendorExtensions}}
    {{#x-rate-limit}}
    $values['{{name}}'] = {{value}};
    {{/x-rate-limit}}
    {{^x-rate-limit}}
    $values['max'] = RateLimiting::MAX_LIMIT;
    $values['period'] = RateLimiting::TIMEOUT;
    {{/x-rate-limit}}
    {{/vendorExtensions}}
```

On a path that doesn't have the `x-rate-limit` defined, it correctly prints the following

```
    $values['max'] = RateLimiting::MAX_LIMIT;
    $values['period'] = RateLimiting::TIMEOUT;
```

On a path that does have, it prints the following

```
    $values[''] = ;
    $values[''] = ;
```

If I print `{{.}}` inside the `{{#x-rate-limit}}` and `{{/x-rate-limit}}`, I get the following:

```
{&quot;name&quot;:&quot;max&quot;,&quot;value&quot;:20,&quot;description&quot;:&quot;The max amount of requests allowed within the period&quot;}}
```

So it's correctly iterating over the array of objects, I'm able to print them out, but I can't access the items inside those objects.

Is there something that I'm missing here? Everything seems correct to me?

Answer (score 0):

Try using this template:

```
{{#vendorExtensions.x-rate-limit}}
$values['{{name}}'] = {{value}};
{{/vendorExtensions.x-rate-limit}}
{{^vendorExtensions.x-rate-limit}}
$values['max'] = RateLimiting::MAX_LIMIT;
$values['period'] = RateLimiting::TIMEOUT;
{{/vendorExtensions.x-rate-limit}}
```